# How to limit nodes appearance on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have node named "sprite" and when i touch screen it shows up for 1 sec on specific x axis, after that "sprite" node disappear, i want to make that on screen can be only two "sprite" nodes at the same time  and they can't be on same spot.. Because  for now i can add "sprite" nodes as much as my fingers can tap on screen. here what i got for now:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

    CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchlocation.x, 60);

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board_ipad@2x"];

    sprite.xScale = 0.4;
    sprite.yScale = 0.6;
    sprite.position = location;
    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
    sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    sprite.name = boardCategoryName;

    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
    SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,remove]];
    [sprite runAction:actionSequence];

    [self addChild:sprite];

}
}
```

**Edited**

```
@implementation GameScene
SKNode *groupSprite;

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
    groupSprite  = [[SKNode alloc]init];
    [self addChild:groupSprite];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {


    if (groupSprite.children.count < 2) {



        CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchlocation.x, 75);

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board_ipad@2x"];

            sprite.xScale = 0.4;
            sprite.yScale = 0.6;

        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = boardCategory;
        sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;
        sprite.name = boardCategoryName;


        SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
        SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,remove]];
        [sprite runAction:actionSequence];

        [groupSprite addChild:sprite];


    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an array like @kaizoku has pointed out, but that is just a variable that is floating out there making the code possibly unmanageable.  A better approach would be to use an SKNode to create a group,  then check the group count.

(My objective c is a bit rusty, so please bear with me)

```
...

SKNode *groupSprite = [[SKNode alloc] init];

...

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view 
{
    self.addChild(groupSprite);
}

...

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) 
    {
        if(groupSprite.children.count < 2)
        {
            CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
            CGPoint location = CGPointMake(touchlocation.x, 60);
            SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"board_ipad@2x"];

            sprite.xScale = 0.4;
            sprite.yScale = 0.6;
            sprite.position = location;
            sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.frame.size];
            sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
            sprite.name = boardCategoryName;

            SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
            SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
            SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,remove]];
            [sprite runAction:actionSequence];

            [groupSprite addChild:sprite];

        }
    }
}
```

The reason you want to do it this way, is because it makes your code more readable.  You have a scene, with a group of sprites, that contains sprites.  Now if for some reason you want to remove all the sprites from the screen.  You just remove it from the group, you do not need to worry about removing it from the scene AND removing it from an array.

Comment: Iam kind a new to programming and objective c, but this line `SKNode* groupSprite = SKNode();` is it swift? because i got  an error for Unexpected interface name, and when i search on mother google, swift shows up, but i cant find how to write in objective c

Comment: Like I said my objective c is rusty,  I do not know offhand what the shorthand for [[SKNode alloc] init] is,  [SKNode node] maybe?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so i tried your example i change `SKNode* groupSprite = SKNode();` to `
SKNode *groupSprite = [[SKNode alloc] init];` and now original sprite doesnt show up on screen at all

Comment: did you add the group to the scene like I said to do?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon excuse me, how I can do it? i did everything you write in your post

Comment: -(void) didMoveToView()
{
    self.addChild(groupSprite); 
}  This line

Comment: @Knight0fDragon only difference what i did is `-(void) didMoveToView(){SKNote *groupSprite =[[SKNote alloc]init]; [self addchild:groupSprite];}` because if i declare before  didMoveToView() get me an error

Comment: well that doesnt work at all, then groupSprite is not global to the class.  What error are you getting here

Comment: you are using the GameScenes didMoveToView,  not create a new function right?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes, i put my code in my post, so you can see whats wrong

Comment: I do not see any changes

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thank you so much, now it works, I tried to figure it out all day!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an Array of SKSpriteNode type.

   var yourArray = [SKSpriteNode]
2. When you touch, add the new node in this array.

   yourArray.append(sprire)
3. When your touch function is executed, check if the array size is more than two. If it is, do not do anything.

   if yourArray.count < 2 {
   //Your code
   }